# How to add the integers in one list to another in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists using python, let's say:

```
lst = [1, 1, 2]
lst2 = [1, 1]
```

And I'm trying to "add" the elemtents of `lst` with `lst2` such that I get:
`[2, 2, 2]`

I have tried doing:

```
lst + lst2
```

This only get's me `[1, 1, 2, 1, 1,]`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with `fillvalue=0`:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

lst = [a + b for a, b in zip_longest(lst, lst2, fillvalue=0)]
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```py
[2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [sum(pair) for pair in itertools.zip_longest(lst, lst2, fillvalue=0)]
[2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer to do it without iterator:

```
lst3 = [lst[i]+lst2[i] for i in range(min(len(lst), len(lst2)))]+lst[min(len(lst), len(lst2)):]+lst2[min(len(lst), len(lst2)):]
```

Comment: why do you prefer this? it is ugly IMO